# Redirect URL if it contains at least 5 segments and the first segment is blog

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all URLs that has **blog** as segment 1 and if there are at least 5 segments.

for example: domain.com/blog/entry/title/2012/P5 will redirect to domain.com/blog

domain.com/blog/entry/2013 will not redirect since it does not have at least 5 segments.

domain.com/blog/entry/2013/P5/title/howdy/test will redirect to domain.com/blog because it has atleast 5 segments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule at top of **`/blog/.htaccess`** (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/){3}[^/]+(?:/.*)?$ /blog [L,R=302]
```

If `/blog` is not a real directory then use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(?:[^/]+/){3}[^/]+(?:/.*)?$ /$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```